# Jquery add active class depending on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

i am creating one page website with scroll to plugin. I want to add active class to menu items depending on how far i scroll.

Navigation: About us | Services | Prices | Contacts

if i scroll from 0 to 800 pixels from top than About us will be active,
if i scroll from 800 to 1600 pixels from top than Services will be active

and so on...

Thanx

Comment: so you ask us to write your code?

Comment: only a function which will add class depending on scroll position

Comment: something like: $(window).scroll(function(){
  
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 0 ){ 
   $("#menu .item1").addClass("active")
   
  }
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution, i am using scrollspy plugin, it is included into bootstarp and uikit, you can download uikit with many other useful features from: http://www.getuikit.com/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my questuion.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
$(".top_menu a.active").removeClass("active");
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll <= 800) {
    $(".top_menu .item1").addClass("active");
}
else if (scroll <= 1600) {
    $(".top_menu .item2").addClass("active");
}
else if (scroll <= 2400) {
    $(".top_menu .item3").addClass("active");
}
else if (scroll <= 3200) {
    $(".top_menu .item4").addClass("active");
}
else if (scroll <= 4000) {
    $(".top_menu .item5").addClass("active");
}
else if (scroll <= 4800) {
    $(".top_menu .item6").addClass("active");
}
```

});

Comment: what if your theme was responsive or your parent element collapse or any of your contents changed?

Comment: i have no solution for responsive theme

Comment: i found a better solution, i am using scroll spy plugin, you can also use ui kit with a lot of useful things getuikit.com, scrollspy is included there, and well written documentation is included.